# How early can I enter Japan on a tourist visa?

Tags: visa, japan

Can I go to Japan before my tourist visa starts?

Comment: No? Why else would there be a start date on it, it it wasn't meant to be the start date?

Answer (score 5):

No.  If you need a visa to enter Japan, you cannot legally enter Japan before your visa starts.